# How can I remove the left margin that occurs when using isscrollable?

Tags: flutter, dart

When I do not use 'isScrollable: true', it works normally without any problems, but when I use it, there is a blank space on the left like this picture.

[image]

If you scroll to the right, it's normal.

What is the problem? and how can I solve it?

```
tabBar() {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 6,
      animationDuration: Duration.zero,
      child: TabBar(
        isScrollable: true,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
        unselectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(
          fontSize: 14,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
          color: Color(0xFF000000),
        ),
        labelPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
        labelStyle: const TextStyle(
          fontSize: 14,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
          color: Color(0xFFffffff),
        ),
        indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
        indicator: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          color: const Color(0xFF000000),
        ),
        tabs: [
        .
        .
        .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While using `isscrollable:true`, the default `tabAlignment` is `TabAlignment.center`. You can use

```dart
child: TabBar(
  isScrollable: true,
  tabAlignment: TabAlignment.start,
```

More about [tab-alignment.](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/tab-alignment)